# Symbolic Logic - Quantifier Proof (w/ Conditionals)

Tags: symbolic-logic, fitch

[image: What I have so far]

I'm not sure if lines 6 - 7 & 8 - 11 are being done correctly. I feel like it's necessary to prove 12 which proves the rest of the problem.

I'm a bit stuck on lines 8 - 11. I initially tried to do it straight up. I couldn't see what I was doing wrong so I tried adding in sub-proofs but that complicated everything.

Anyone have any hints on where to go next with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use **or**-elim on 1) considering two separate cases.

1st case : **Dodec(x) and Large(x)**, from which, with 3) and assuming **Small(x)**, derive a contradiction and then **FrontOf(x,c)**.

2nd case **Cube(x) and Small(x)**, from which, with 2), derive **FrontOf(x,c)**.

Comment: Sorry I'm still a bit confused. Why do I have to drive FrontOf(x) in this case for the sub-sub-proofs (6 - 7  & 8 - 11)? -- In which case how can I fix 8 - 11? I read through your "1st case" and I'm still lost. I've tried to derive a contradiction but the quantifier gets in the way so should I make another subproof for it?

Comment: @J.Martinez - from 6) derive Cube(x) and from 2) use forall-elim and then to-elim to derive FrontOf(x,c).

Comment: @J.Martinez - that is 6,7,12,14 of your proof.

Comment: 8-11 is simply wrong; you have to assume Small(x) and with the second case of or-elim : Dodec(x) and Large(x) derive Small(x) and Large(x), This contradicts 3 and it is (quite) done.

Comment: This ended up being a lot more complicated than I thought but I managed to figure it out. Thank you so much for your patience and assistance!

Comment: @J.Martinez - you are welcome :-)

Answer (score 1):

The form of 'v elimination' is a Proof by Cases.  You raise two subproofs, by assuming the cases of a given disjunction in turn, with the goal in each to derive the same conclusion.

```
| A v B   Given [Premise, Assumption, or Derived]
|  -
|  |_ A   Assumption
|  |  :
|  |  C   Derived
|  -
|  |_ B   Assumption
|  |  :
|  |  C   Derived
|  -
|  C      v Elimination
```

So you will have

```
|_ [f] S(f)                       Assumption
|  (D(f) ^ L(f)) v (C(f) ^ S(f))  Universal Elimination
|  |_ D(f) ^ L(f)                 Assumption
|  |  L(f)                        Conjunction Elimination
|  |  :
|  |  ~~F(f)                      Negation Elimination
|  |  F(f)                        Double Negation Elimination
|  -
|  |_ C(f) ^ S(f)                 Assumption
|  |  C(f)                        Conjunction Elimination
|  |  C(f) -> F(f)                Universal Elimination
|  |  F(f)                        Disjunction Elimination               
|  F(f)                           Disjunction Elimination
Ax (S(x) -> F(x))                 Universal Introduction
```

Comment: In that case what should be done for Step 8 - 11?

Comment: As Eliran advised, use Reduction to Absurdity to derive what you need.  You should be able to see what contradictions you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Here's roughly how to get from your Small(f) assumption (line 4) to Cube(f).

```
 4. S(f)
 5. | D(f) & L(f)
 6. | | ~C(f)
 7. | | L(f)&S(f)           [contradicts 3]
 8. | C(f)
 9. (D(f) & L(f)) -> C(f)
10. | C(f) & S(f)
11. | C(f)
12. (C(f) & S(f)) -> C(f)      
13. C(f)                     v-elimination
```

Comment: Line 7 doesn't work because of the quantifier. Also why is 9 needed?

Comment: @J.Martinez   Different proof systems use different versions of the rules.  Eliran is using that R is infered from P v Q, P -> R, and Q -> R .   Since these conditionals are usually derived by subproofs, your proof checker allows a shortcut of directly using those subproofs.

Answer (score 0):

To make this work in the proof checker I am using I made the following substitutions:

- Dodec(x) is replaced with Dx.
- Large(x) is replaced with Lx.
- Cube(x) is replaced with Cx.
- Small(x) is replaced with Sx.
- FrontOf(xc) is replaced with Fxc.

[image]

---

References

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Winter 2018. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/

Comment: This looks a lot more complicated than I initially thought it would be. Is there possibly another way? -- Also for step 6 using DeMorgan's intro rule (~) doesn't work.

Comment: @J.Martinez Are you saying about step 6 that DeMorgan's rule is not permitted in your proof checker? This is a derived rule. Page 141-2 of *forallx* give 10-line derivations of both forms.